# Cannot get value from Accelerometer, Gyro and DeviceMotion

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3, xcode8, cmmotionmanager

I'm making an app to track your sleep by getting any movement of the iPhone. I searched everywhere and there are many ways you can get data from this but non worked. Here's my code.

```
func startManager() {
    let manager = CMMotionManager()
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    let accelerometer = manager.accelerometerData
}
```

But manager.accelerometerData is nil. I also tried it with DeviceMotion, Gyro and UserAcceleration, non of them worked. I also tried this.

```
print(manager.isAccelerometerActive)
```

It printed **false** so I think this is the problem but I still cannot make it active.

I tried putting the *let manager = CMMotionManager()* to the top and it still won't work.

I tried putting *manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()* in the ViewDidLoad and still doesn't work.

I also tried another way which is this.

```
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (data : CMAccelerometerData, error : Error) in
        print(data)
    }
```

but it gave me an error saying that I have to add *as! CMAccelerometerHandler* but after I added that it tell me to add it again.

I want to get raw value from the Accelerometer as x, y and z

(I imported CoreMotion)

I'm doing this using Swift 3 on XCode 8.2.1 and testing it on iPhone 6s.

Answer (score 0):

In `Swift3`, you should use optional parameters in the handler

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(
    to: OperationQueue.main , 
    withHandler:{ (data : CMAccelerometerData?, error : Error?) in
       print(data)
})
```